# Unable to access internal websites that starts with HTTP when I run powershell command to check website status

Tags: powershell, http, website, url, uri

I'm getting "Unable to run/search" for the status for http://example.com/ but for those that starts with HTTPS:// has no issue, I am getting Status: 200 with OK. What I need to add on my script so it can also test those sites that starts with http:// ?

Below powershell script I tried and works fine for those websites that starts with HTTPS://

```
$Uris = 'https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.yahoo.com','http://example.com/'
$PathTxt = "C:\temp\Uri.txt" 
$PathCsv = "C:\temp\Uri.csv" 
$uriList = @()
foreach ($uri in $Uris){
    $uriObject = New-Object PSObject
    Try{
        $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -ErrorAction Stop
        $uriObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "URL" -Value $Response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri
        $uriObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value $Response.StatusCode
        $uriObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Description" -Value $Response.StatusDescription
        $uriObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Website Name" -Value $Response.StatusDescription
        Write-Host $Response.StatusCode $Response.StatusDescription $Response.BaseResponse.ResponseUri -ForegroundColor Green
        $uriList += $uriObject
    }
    Catch{
        Write-Host "Unable to reach $uri" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
$uriList | Out-File -FilePath $PathTxt
$uriList | Export-Csv -Path $PathCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: what error msg do you get when you run `I-WR` on that http uri _without disabling error msgs_?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried below, let me know if I ran it correctly. I'm new on powershell. seems I don't have access, that link is our internal directory which works fine if I open it on web browser. 

'C:\PowerShell> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http:// example.com/ -DisableKeepAlive -TimeoutSec 20 -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable WebRequestError'

Invoke-WebRequest : 
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
 You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials 
that you supplied.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I managed to resolve the issue by adding -UseDefaultCredentials. Thanks

Comment: ah! glad to know that you found the problem and the fix! [*grin*] you have shown one lovely example of why hiding error msgs can be problematic. there are times when it is needed ... but once you start debugging, you REALLY wanna see those error  msgs ... [*grin*]

Comment: Can you give us the results of this command while you are having the problem: netstat -aon | findstr "80"